# how to extract the link of the website which are using my url in their website using python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, seo, google-search-console

i want to know which website is using my website link in their websites.Can i get a python code to do so?

i was trying to get all the websites which are using my website link but i am not able to do so

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

### [Google Search Operators](https://ahrefs.com/blog/google-advanced-search-operators/)

**allintext:**
Similar to “intext,” but only results containing all of the specified words somewhere on the page will be returned.

**Example:**
[image]

### Python Code

We can go ahead and use the above functionality provided by Google Search with Python to get a list of all of the websites that contain your website link inside their text.

For that we can go ahead and use the following Python Module.

```
try:
    from googlesearch import search
except ImportError:
    print("No module named 'google' found")
 
# to search
query = "allintext:https://yourwebsite.com/" # replace with your website link in allintext
 
for j in search(query, num=10, stop=10, pause=2):
    print(j)
```

### [Learn More](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/performing-google-search-using-python-code/)